# Minikube Start Error (Kubernetes) When Using hyperv Driver on Windows server 2016

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to install Kubernetes on windows server 2016.
I tried to install minikube, and got some errors.

This is the tutorial that I followed:

https://www.assistanz.com/installing-minikube-on-windows-2016-server/

This is the command + error that I got:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> minikube start –vm-driver=hyperv –hyperv-virtual-switch=Minikube
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM... Downloading Minikube ISO
170.78 MB / 170.78 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
E1106 19:29:10.616564   11852 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path.

Retrying.
E1106 19:29:10.689675   11852 start.go:174] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
================================================================================
    An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?
To opt out of these messages, run the command:
        minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]:
```

**Someone knows how to solve it?
I googled it, but no luck.**

Thanks!

Comment: any updates in your case? Did the answer help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the config parameters to work with `minikube start`.

I was able to get past this error using the `minikube config` [commands](https://darkowlzz.github.io/post/minikube-config/) in PowerShell (should also work at a command prompt):

```
minikube config set vm-driver hyperv 
minikube config set hyperv-virtual-switch ExternalSwitch
minikube config view
minikube delete
minikube start
```

For more information on the command run: `minikube config -h`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation you have provided, I have noticed that the screenshot shows a slight difference to the one they've quote.

I have also found this command in another piece of documentation from kubernetes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/), showing the same command as that from the screenshot.

I suggest you try the following command;

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch=Minikube
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, the command that you suggested - its the same command that I run (check my command in the post). As I said, it did not work. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that OP has pasted the incorrect command, because there is `-` instead of `--`. I tried to pass this arguments to minikube and all you get is an instant error. So the issue must be somewhere else. I remember having similar issue and it got resolved after deleting the .kube and .minikube folders and trying to run it again.

After taking a closer look this tutorial is destined for installation of minikube inside of a Windows Server 2016 Virtual Machine, so you have to have a Nested Virtualization able hardware:

> Prerequisites The Hyper-V host and guest must both be Windows Server
>   2016/Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later. VM configuration version
>   8.0 or greater. An Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology -- nesting is currently Intel-only. There are some differences with
>   virtual networking for second-level virtual machines. See "Nested
>   Virtual Machine Networking".

**So the main question is, is that true in your scenario? Are you trying to perform your steps on Windows Server Hyper-V virtual machine with nested virtualization feature?**

If you confirm that I have technical possibilities to check it in that scenario.
Otherwise I recommend using the "traditional way" of running minikube in Windows, according for example to this [tutorial.](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c)